# I'm trying to quit a python program with q or Q as an option

Tags: python

I am trying to quit a python program with either "q" or "Q"
but when I put in "Q" it give an error message about the syntax being incorrect.

```
   else:
            print("That was an invalid response. Enter a number or 'q' to quit.")
    # <<Check correctness of user's response>>
    if response == 'q''Q':
        keep_asking_questions = False
```

I tried replacing
**if response == 'q''Q':**
and
**if response == 'q,Q':**

none worked.

Comment: The first one asks if `response` is equal to the two characters `qQ`; the second if it is literally the three characters `q,Q`. To test if it is one of the following characters, `response in 'qQ'`; if you want one of the following strings, `response in ['q', 'Q']`.

Comment: Nope,  wrote if response == ['q', 'Q']: still say's it's a invalid response unless I put the end bracket in the wrong place maybe.

Comment: What does if response.lower() do ?